# show/hide dynamically added divs using jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, dynamic-html

I have a little combobox allowing a user to select the number of family members they want to register for an event. But if the family members are not U.S. Citizens, I want to show a second set of options for them to enter.  I can dynamically add the elements, but I don't know how to show/hide the citizenship fields.

I'm new to jQuery and so I'm probably doing this the wrong way, but here's the function that adds the fields:

```
function familySize() {
        while (famElements < $("#famNum").val()) { // add fields
                    addFields = '<div class="member"> Name:&nbsp;<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" required> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="cit" type="checkbox" onChange="citizenInfo()" >&nbsp;&nbsp;Non U.S. Citizen?<br/></div> <div class="citInfo" style="display:none"> <input id="countryCitizenship" type="text" placeholder="Citizenship" required> </div>';
                    document.getElementById('famItems').innerHTML += addFields;
                    famElements++;
                }
        while (famElements > $("#famNum").val()) { // remove fields
            console.log("remove one");
             $('#famItems div:last').remove();
             famElements--;
        }
    }

<div id="famItems">
            </div>
```

The style="display:none" on the citInfo div does hide it initially but I just need to figure out how to capture the clicks on the checkboxes to hide/show the citizenship text inputs.

Comment: you can hide/show div with .hide() and .show() methods. Adding a click event is .click(function() { code to execute here });

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like I didn't define my problem clearly enough.  I can add the checkboxes and the <onChange="citizenInfo()> argument works.  citizenInfo() gets called just fine.  It's just that I don't know what to do inside that method.  How do I access the div below the checkbox (citInfo) and toggle it's visibility on and off based on the state of the checkbox?

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to handle events of dynamically created items.

```
$(function(){
    $('#cit').live('change', citizenInfo());
});
```

Comment: Or even better, use `.delegate()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, just use a selector instead of `getElementById()` and use `append()` to add content to it.

Also, you should never have two items with the same ID. You can sort it out by appending your `famElements` counter to the IDs of your input fields. As this change ruled out selecting the elements by ID, I also changed your checkboxes to have a class `cit`, so I can attach the event using an easy selector.

For the click event, you can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) so you don't have to keep binding events all the time.

```
function familySize() {
    while (famElements < $("#famNum").val()) { // add fields
        famElements++;
        addFields = '<div class="member"> Name:&nbsp;<input id="name'+famElements+'" type="text" placeholder="Name" required> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input class="cit" id="cit'+famElements+'" type="checkbox" onChange="citizenInfo()" >&nbsp;&nbsp;Non U.S. Citizen?<br/></div> <div class="citInfo" style="display:none"> <input id="countryCitizenship'+famElements+'" type="text" placeholder="Citizenship" required></div>';
        $('#famItems').append(addFields);
    }
    while (famElements > $("#famNum").val()) { // remove fields
        console.log("remove one");
        $('#famItems div:last').remove();
        famElements--;
    }
}

// Your jQuery ready function
$(function(){
    // Click event on checkboxes
    $('#famItems').delegate('.cit','click',function(){
        var $this = $(this);

            // Show or hide the div
        if($this.is(':checked')){
            $this.parent().find('.citInfo').hide();
        } else {
            $this.parent().find('.citInfo').show();
        }
    });
});
```

You can build your elements more elegantly with jQuery, but it does what it needs to do. Although you might consider doing that in case you add to your HTML and that big lump of text becomes too much of a mystery.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply. I tried this code though and it doesn't seem to work. The $funcion() gets called on start up but since the familySize() is called when the combobox is changed, the checkbox handler never gets called. How do I associate this function with the checkboxes.

Comment: @solerous: I admit this code is completely untested. The `delegate()` binds the event handler against your container div `#famItems`, so as long as that exists at the time of document ready and it's never destroyed, it should work. Please note that because of the ID fix, I have added a `cit` class on your checkboxes to make the selector easier, make sure you put it on them too when testing.

Comment: Well, #famItems will exist but the cit divs will not. Can it bind to clicks on undefined items?

Comment: Yes, `delegate()` works just like `live()` in the context of a container element. `live()` would be the same as delegating a handler to `document`.

Answer (score -1):

I finally figured it out just through sheer trial and error.  If I enclose both the "member" div and the "citInfo" div in another div and then change the checkbox definition to this:

```
<input class="cit" onChange="citizenInfo(this)" type="checkbox">
```

then all I need is this function:

```
function citizenInfo(chkBox) {
 $(chkBox).parent().parent().find('.citInfo').toggle();
}
```